# Trouble accessing recently created ODBC table

Tags: r, oracle, odbc, rodbc, r-dbi

I have started using `DBI` and `RODBC` packages as a way to talk to the ODBC interface and write a dataframe as a ODBC table to be accessible during queries.

My problem is, while I can write a table by using either `dbWriteTable`or `sqlSave`, I can't access it.

When I explore the available tables on my ODBC connection, my test table appears in my personal schema but when I try to access it via `SELECT` or even `desc` the "table or view does not exist" error appears.

The problem is only accessing the database because I can properly update or remove the table using either ODBC R package or even using SQL Developer.

PS: If I create the table using the import function in SQL Developer I can properly access the table but my goal is to properly access it after writing it using an R function

Comment: can you give us some example data - perhaps the connection string, db commands you are using and the full error message?

Comment: The commands i am using are `sqlSave`and `dbWriteTable` with a simple test data.frame being created in my current schema. The error is ORA-00942 Table or View does not exist...